# How to find the max value in a portion of a column and then divide all the values for it

Tags: r, for-loop, search, dataframe, data-manipulation

I have a df's column with values belonging to different pools. Every pool has 61 records, after which the second pool starts.
I'm trying to search inside the 61 records of every pool the max value, then divide all the pool'records for it, store the result into a new column and finally continue with the next pool below.

for the first pools, for example, I can use this code,

```
db$result <- db$value/max(db$value[1:61])
db$result <- db$value/max(db$value[62:123])
```

and so on...
But how I can do the operation recursively in all the db without having to manually change the intervals?
if it can help, I have also a column of the df with the pools'name

Comment: Please consider providing a reproducible example.

Comment: Create a "pool-id" variable that identifies each pool and then run your analysis with a grouping function like `ave` from base R, dplyr, data.table, ... etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution using `rollapply` from `zoo` package can be,

```
library(zoo)
library(reshape2)
v1 <- rollapply(db$value, 61, by = 61, function(i) i/max(i))
db$result <- melt(t(v1))$value
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `gl` to create a grouping variable and then use `ave` to get the `max` for each of the unique groups, divide 'value' by that output

```
db$result <- with(db, value/ave(value, as.numeric(gl(length(value), 61, 
                                length(value))),FUN = max))
```

---

Another option if the number of rows is a multiple of 61 will be to convert the 'value' to a `matrix`, get the `colMaxs`, divide by it and convert to a `vector`.

```
 library(matrixStats)
 m1 <- matrix(db$value, ncol=3)
 db$result <- c(m1/colMaxs(m1)[col(m1)])
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
db <- data.frame(value = rnorm(61*3))
```

Answer (score 0):

I am adding my solution with dplyr function pool where x is argument how many questions are in pool

```
 df<-data.frame(value=1:183,result=round(runif(183,min=10,max=90),0))

library(dplyr)
pool<-function(x){

    df$group<-ceiling(df$value/x)
    df<-df%>%group_by(group)%>%mutate(ratio=result/max(result,na.rm=TRUE))
    df
}

res<-pool(61)
```

Answer (score 0):

I did a solution that uses max(), quotient, and subsetting. It became quite ugly in the end due to sapply not working out (had to lapply/unlist) and the application of rep, but I am posting it for completeness:

```
#creating test db with five intervals
db <- data.frame("codenum"=1:(61*5))
db$result <- sample(1:99, (61*5), replace = T)

#the actual function that solves the problem
db$maxval <- unlist(lapply(c(0:(length(db$result) %/% 61 - 1)), function(x) rep(max(db$result[(1+61*x):((61*(x+1)))]), 61)))

#explicit testing of the five intervals
max(db$result[1:61])
max(db$result[62:122])
max(db$result[123:183])
max(db$result[183:244])
max(db$result[245:305])
```